# Como faço para implementar ‘sign in with google’ in meu aplicativo android?

Tags: android, android-fragment, google

Estou com a dificuldade de integra o 'Sign in with google' no meu app, segui a [documentação](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started), não esta dando certo.

alguma dica e ajuda?

Comment: Exatamente o que deu errado? Melhore sua pergunta para ajudarmos...sua pergunta ficou muito "vaga".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agnaldo, o post do AndroidHive me ajudou bastante na implementação do login do Google +!

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: Não entendi porque alguém deu -1. Achei o tutorial ótimo para entender a implementação :)

Comment: Resposta que dependente de um *link* é tenso, você podia fazer um resumo do que era explicado lá? Assim a sua resposta não torna-se inválida se o *link* quebrar. A propósito, está quebrado :) **-1**

Comment: @renan acho que não está mais, mas concordo com você, se isso tudo estivesse numa resposta, com certeza seria uma das melhores aqui para explicar essa integração. De qualquer modo, na falta de uma resposta completa, uma resposta parcial é melhor do que nada. **+1**

Answer (score 3):

Até há algumas semanas, eu estava utilizando o Google Plus para autenticação em nosso aplicativo.
Porém, a Google recentemente lançou um excelente toolkit para autenticação nos aplicativos.

Chama-se Google Identity Toolkit.

Recomendo você utilizar essa nova engine para autenticação, pois além de puder autenticar com o Google Plus, você também poderá adicionar botão para login com Facebook, Microsoft Account entre outros.
Dê uma olhada nesse link:
https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/